# Condition for a sequence compound random variables to converge in probability.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of [compound random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) with a random parameter $Y$. A concrete example is that $Y \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$ and $X_n \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,Y)/n$.

Assume that $X_n \to y$ almost surely conditioning on $Y=y$. In other words
$$
\mathbb P \{\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n = \liminf_{n\to\infty} X_n = y~|~Y=y\} = 1.
$$

My questions are:

1. Is it true that we have $X_n \to Y$ in probability?
2. If not, is there a general condition that makes $X_n \to Y$ in probability?
3. How do we formally define the above conditional probability when $\mathrm{P}(Y=y)=0$, e.g., when $Y$ is a continuous random variable?

Any reference on this topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: $\frac{X_n}{n} \to y$ when $Y = y$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming that $\Bbb{P}(\lim_n X_n = y \mid Y=y) = 1$ for each $y$, then

   \begin{align*}
   \Bbb{P}(X_n \to Y)
   &= \int_{0}^{1} \Bbb{P}( X_n \to Y \mid Y = y ) \, dy \\
   &= \int_{0}^{1} \Bbb{P}( X_n \to y \mid Y = y ) \, dy
   = \int_{0}^{1} dy = 1.
   \end{align*}

   So we have $X_n \to Y$ almost surely under $\Bbb{P}$.
2. By the Chebyshev's inequality,

   $$ \Bbb{P}(|X_n - y| > \epsilon \mid Y = y) \leq \frac{y(1-y)}{n\epsilon^2}. $$

   This bounds gives

   $$ \Bbb{P}(|X_n - Y| > \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2} \int_{0}^{1} y(1-y)\, dy = \frac{1}{6n\epsilon^2}. $$

   This shows that $X_n \to Y$ in probability.
3. It is usually realized in terms of [*regular condition probability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability).